# How to run the object file in remote computer?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a scenario please take a look.

I have two Pcs one is windows and another is ubuntu.
I have installed laravel (PHP) on windows and the necessary files.
On ubuntu, there is only an Object file.

What am i doing is:
on click of a button (from windows) run a function which will connect to ubuntu pc with its credentials,
and run the command to launch that Object file in ubuntu.

How can I achieve this with laravel? any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are probably looking to make an SSH connection and run a command

Comment: Yes, Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is ssh connection

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('server_address', 'port');

ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'your terminal ubuntu command');
```

see more info here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

Comment: Hi @Eden Moshe, ssh2_connect can i use with laravel? or i have to install any extension for that?

Comment: ssh2_connect is php function, Laravel also written in php, so any function in php will be supported under Laravel. 
[read more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php)